# Processing input from textbox and file in PHP form

Tags: php, html, css, web

I have tried making a html and php page for taking input and processing them respectively. In the HTML page, user is given a option of either give a text or upload the file.

```
<form action="target.php" method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data"       id="form">
<table  width="950px" align="center">
<tr>
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  class="table1"  border="0">
<tr valign="middle" align="left"><td width="15" height="10"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr valign="middle" align="left">
<td width="15"></td>
<td><font color="White">input1</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <td width="15"></td>
  <td>
  <font color="Red"><input type="file" name="file" size="42"><br></font><font color="White">or paste below:</font><br>
  <textarea name="sequence1" cols="96" rows="7"></textarea><br>     
    </font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Similarly in the PHP page, i could succesfuly transfer the uploaded file from the html page to a varible and run the shell script but unable to process the content from textbox.

```
   <?php
    $a = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $c = (isset($_POST['sequence1'])) ? $_POST['sequence1'] : false;
    if($a!=NULL)
    {
    $output=shell_exec("sh server.sh $a");
     }
    elseif ($c!=NULL){
    $output=shell_exec("sh server.sh $c");}
    else{
    echo No input;}
    ?>
```

Can anybody suggest which would help me to solve this problem.

Comment: either write a temp file with the contents of the textarea or modify server.sh to take a string

Comment: I have tried writing to a temp file with the contents of the textarea as suggested in the other comment. But didnot work.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
    $file=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
}elseif(!empty($_POST['sequence1'])){

    $file = tmpfile();
    fwrite($file, $_POST['sequence1']);
    fclose($file);

}else{
    ///errror
}

 $output=shell_exec("sh server.sh $file");
```

Comment: I have tried this!!But did not work. I have tried to echo the variable $file after giving input in the text box. it gives the output Resource id #2. I dont think it is written to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this lines to the code should work!!

```
   elseif(isset($_POST['sequence1'])){
    $c=$_POST['sequence1'];
    $f1='temp1.txt';
    file_put_contents($f1, $c);
  else{
///errror
  }
  $output=shell_exec("sh server.sh $f1");
```